# How do I run each module with different commands in maven reactor

Tags: java, maven

I have around 25 project. Right now, I am building manually one by one. I thought of using maven reactor module.

Each project what I have I run manually with following commands

```
mvn clean install -s devops/ci/maven_setting.xml.
```

This maven_setting.xml have the activeProfiles. Each project will have different activeProfiles.

Now the problem is I am try to run all the projects together by creating maven reactor.

Below is the pom.xml file where I have included all projects.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
 <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
 <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.2</version>
    <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<groupId>com.mt.pom</groupId>
<artifactId>mt-base-retail-pom</artifactId>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
<name>mt-base-retail-pom</name>
 <profiles>
   <profile>
      <id>all-parent-pom</id>
      <modules>
         <module>../mt-base-parent-pom</module>>
         <module>../mt-functional-service-pom</module> etc
      </modules>
   </profile>
   <profile>
      <id>all-common-sdk</id>
      <modules>
         <module>../mt-elasticsearch-starter</module>
         <module>../mt-entity-annotation-processor</module>
         <module>../mt-mongodb-starter</module>
         <module>../mt-neo4j-starter</module>
         <module>../mt-sql-starter</module>  etc
      </modules>
    </profile>
   </profiles>
</project>
```

Now when I try to build all-common-sdk projects with

```
mvn clean install -P all-common-sdk
```

Each project need to pick up the maven_setting.xml from its own subfolder which is not happening.

How to make the maven_setting.xml as part of maven modules.

Note: This maven_settings.xml will have different active profiles for each project.

Please let me if there is any other way as well so that I can build all projects at a time in single shot.

Comment: Why: `Each project need to pick up the maven_setting.xml ` is this neccesary???